Dynamically subtract space to make two tcolorbox environments continuous
I have a tcolorbox environment defined as:
\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{\sffamily\bfseries\color{purple!40!black} Lemma}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{
    enhanced,
    colback=purple!8,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{purple!70},
    breakable,
}

Additionally, I have a proof environment defined as:
\newtheorem*{lemprooff}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{purple!40!black} Proof}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemprooff}{
    enhanced,
    colback=purple!2,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{purple!70},
    breakable,
}
\AtEndEnvironment{lemprooff}{\null\hfill$\qedsymbol$}
\newenvironment{lemproof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-12.5pt}\begin{lemprooff}}{\end{lemprooff}}

which I want to have right after the lemma as in this picture:

The problem is that using \vspace{-12.5pt} means that in some pages it will be perfect, but in most it will be either separated, as in this picture:

or overlapping the lemma, which is not good. Is there a way to dynamically calculate this space so that it always snuggly fits without being separated or overlapping?
Some things I have tried are:
\newenvironment{lemproof}[1][\proofname]{\unskip\noindent\begin{lemprooff}}{\end{lemprooff}}
\newenvironment{lemproof}[1][\proofname]{\unskip\par\noindent\begin{lemprooff}}{\end{lemprooff}}

Neither worked all the time.
A full snippet where I use a smaller \vspace to recreate the issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{\sffamily\bfseries\color{purple!40!black} Lemma}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemma}{
    enhanced,
    colback=purple!8,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{purple!70},
    breakable,
}

\newtheorem*{lemprooff}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{purple!40!black} Proof}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lemprooff}{
    enhanced,
    colback=purple!2,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{purple!70},
    breakable,
}
\AtEndEnvironment{lemprooff}{\null\hfill$\qedsymbol$}
\newenvironment{lemproof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-6pt}\begin{lemprooff}}{\end{lemprooff}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
    Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $ca = cb$ and $c\neq 0$, then $a = b$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemproof}
    If $c > 0$, then $a = b$ is obvious. If $c < 0$, then $-c > 0$ and $-ca = -cb$, so $-a = -b$ and $a = b$.
\end{lemproof}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{lemma}
    Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $ca = cb$ and $c\neq 0$, then $a = b$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemproof}
    If $c > 0$, then $a = b$ is obvious. If $c < 0$, then $-c > 0$ and $-ca = -cb$, so $-a = -b$ and $a = b$.
\end{lemproof}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{lemma}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemproof}
    If $c > 0$, then $a = b$ is obvious. If $c < 0$, then $-c > 0$ and $-ca = -cb$, so $-a = -b$ and $a = b$.
\end{lemproof}

\begin{lemma}
    Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $ca = cb$ and $c\neq 0$, then $a = b$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemproof}
    If $c > 0$, then $a = b$ is obvious. If $c < 0$, then $-c > 0$ and $-ca = -cb$, so $-a = -b$ and $a = b$.
\end{lemproof}

\end{document}


Isn't it enough to say after skip=0pt in your \tcolorboxenvironment{lemma} ?

PS: Generally speaking, I would say that you normally don't need general LaTeX-tools like \vspace{-12.5pt}; since tcolorbox should house necessary keys. But I don't know if I have understood your problem 100%.

Using only after skip=0pt doesn't work, since the lemproof still has space above. However, also having before skip=0pt in the lemproof environment does solve that issue. Unfortunately, having the after skip=0pt in the lemma environments means that if no proof is given for a lemma, then the text right after the lemma is stuck to the bottom of the environment with no space. This is easily solved by creating two lemma environments, one for when a proof is given and another for the other case. This is very tedious but, unless I find another solution, will be what I do going forward.

@ kupper Ok, I now understand that sometimes there is no 'proof' (just a 'lemma') and then in 'lemma' the skip keys are unfavorable in relation to the other text. For this purpose, have you ever tried to make just one box out of 'lemma' and 'proof'? In other words 'upper part' and 'lower part', separated by '\tcblower'; whereby the 'lower part' only occurs if there is a 'lower part' = 'proof' at all. That's how I would try to implement it. Would that lead in the right direction?

PS: If that doesn't help, my tip would be:
Try to create an extremely lean example that shows the locations of the problem; but which otherwise contains nothing that has nothing to do with the problem or the problems. So eliminate everything that has nothing to do with the problems. Boxes can contain 'aaa' and 'bbb'; Texts can be \lipsum[66] or similar.

I have tried using upper and lower parts but am unable to get the desired result. It's fine, using the different environments for when there is or no proof is not too bad.

Your second sentence says something like: “It is good the way it is”. Then I don't know what reply post you're hoping for. Your problem seems to occur in places that your code doesn't show - you should clarify that first (if you want an answer...). It's also unclear why you're mixing amsthm and tcolorbox theorems; the latter should be enough.

It is not clear from the example code how the problem manifests itself.
A few points:

It is not elegant to create two (theorem-)environments for the same thing.  The idea of ​​LaTeX is that the author does not have to worry about spacing-problems, these should be set automatically and correctly for him; based on the settings.

tcolorbox usually doesn't need general LaTeX "tricks" like \vspace{6pt}. Corresponding keys are usually available in tcolorbox. You have to look for these in the manual.

It rarely makes sense, and certainly not easier, to create theorem environments as a mishmash of amsmath / amsthm and tcolorbox. If you want a lot of graphics you need tcolorbox, and that's usually enough; tcolorbox should be able to do everything amsthm can do.


As I said, I'm not 100% sure how/where/what/when the problems are, but perhaps the following can be helpful. 
It may be a matter of taste whether you make two boxes out of the lemma and proof or just one in which the lower part (= the proof) is optional; I think it's easier this way with just one box. 
With the method for title / subtitle (='lemma' / 'proof') from here and some other setting, I get:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\colorlet{mytitlecolor}{purple!40!black}
\colorlet{mybglemmacolor}{purple!8}
\colorlet{mybgproofcolor}{mybglemmacolor!44}
\colorlet{myrulecolor}{purple!70}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitlestyle}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{tcbcoltitle}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitle}{}{{\mytitlestyle\tcbtitletext:~}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubtitle}{m}{{\mytitlestyle#1:~}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mylemma}{Lemma}{
%% Left rule ==========
enhanced,
borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myrulecolor},
% ================
boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
sharp corners,
breakable,
  bicolor,
colback=mybglemmacolor,
colbacklower=mybgproofcolor,
%% Title (Lemma) and  Subtitle (Proof) =====
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  coltitle=purple!40!black,% 
  detach title,% title without linebreak  
  before upper=\mytitle,
  before lower = \mysubtitle{Proof},
% =============
}{lem}

\begin{document}
\section{Section with Lemmas}

\begin{mylemma}{}{mymarker}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
\tcblower
Here my proof\dots
\end{mylemma}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{mylemma}{}{}
$1+1=2$
\end{mylemma}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{mylemma}[before lower= {Hint: No proof needed here.}]{}{}
$2\times 2=4$
\tcblower
\end{mylemma}

\begin{mylemma}{}{mymarker2}
\lipsum[66]
\tcblower
\lipsum[64-67]
\end{mylemma}
\end{document}


Hint: I overseen that you want a point instead of a colon; just replace :~ with .-
